# How to write an encrypted value to Registry on install

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

During install I would like to create an encrypted string containing the install date and write that to a Registry key.

I know how to create the encrypted string in code, so I don't need help with the encryption part, I just don't know how to get the installer to:

- get today's date as a string
- call my encryption method on it (from a dll)
- write the result to a registry key if the value does not already exists (no overwrite)

How could I do this please?

Dave

Comment: Are you using the built-in Visual Studio Deployment Projects to generate your MSI?

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a tool that exposed more of the underlying Windows Installer such as WiX or InstallShield, you'd write a simple custom action that got the time, encrypted it and set a property.  Then you would use that property in the Registry table to let the installer write it out during install, remove it during rollback and remove it during uninstall.

However, the project type you are using (and removed from VS2012 FWIW)  doesn't support authoring custom actions in an immeadiate execution context and therefore the custom action can't set a property for use by the Registry table.

This means you'll have to write RollBack, Install and Uninstall custom actions yourself and write to the registry value yourself.

I'd also mention that InstallUtil custom actions have a variety of shortcomings.  I'd do this either in C++ or I'd use WiX DTF to write a C# custom action that appears as a C++ DLL to the installer.